# The text flickers on rotation in kinetic JS in chrome browser

Tags: html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to rotate a text on the click event. It has been achieved but the text flickers on rotation in Google Chrome. It works fine in Mozilla. How to stop this flickering of text. I dont want to slow down the rotation and want rotation on same speed so I dont want to change the duration of transition.Please help.
The code is

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
      canvas { border: 1px solid #9C9898; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v3.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() 
    {
        var angle = 0;
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage(
        {
          container: "container",
          width: 578,
          height: 200
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var text = new Kinetic.Text(
        {
          x:225,
          y: 80,
          text: "Simple",
          fontSize: 12,
          fontFamily: "Calibri",
          textFill: "black"
        });         
        text.on("click", function() 
        {
            angle+=1
            text.transitionTo(
            {
               rotation:Math.PI*angle/2,
               duration:1                   
            });
         });
         layer.add(text);
         stage.add(layer);
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your chrome Canvas settings in chrome://flags

Ensure that "GPU compositing on all pages" is disabled
Ensure that "Enable accelerated CSS animations" is disabled

Comment: I checked that. The settings are already disabled. what else can be done ??